# Is there a generalized formula for recusive Binomial coefficient?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients

Is there any way I can solve the following recursion function?

$$f(n) = \binom{f(n-1)}{2}$$

Or can be written as  $$f(n) = 1/2(f(n-1)(f(n-1) - 1))$$

*f(0) = 4, f(1) = 6, f(2) = 15, ...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s [OEIS A086714](https://oeis.org/A086714), and it grows *very* rapidly. The OEIS entry does not have a closed form, but it does offer the limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)^{1/2^{n+1}}=1.280497808541657066685323460209089278782...$$

Comment: I  see, thanks for the reference.

Comment: @Kasramvd: You’re welcome.